# Electron NodeJS Camera not allowed

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, webcam

I'm developing a system which use the webcam for taking a photo. The script run successfully on the browser (localhost:3000) but on the electron app I get the following error:

> "Not allowed" or "dom permission denied"

How Can I resolve this ?

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error message you are getting?

Comment: Basically it means to I don't have permission. Exactly error messge : NotAllowedError: Permission denied

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045476/how-to-access-camera-webcamera-inside-electron-app

Comment: @coreyp_1 I'm looking for registerStandardSchemes on electron like the answer said.

Comment: the answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045476/how-to-access-camera-webcamera-inside-electron-app) is deprecated .  registerStandardSchemes is not a function